# Hadoop DataNode memory consumption and GC behaviour

Tags: hadoop, garbage-collection, jvm

Recently we have been running into issues with our cluster (CDH 5.3.1), that manifested in both the NameNodes as well as the DataNodes being stuck in long GC cycles varying from 30 sec up to several minutes.

The JVM settings were still the default ones but given that our cluster has in the meanwhile grown to 34 million blocks, the behaviour was explainable.

For the NN a simple adjustment of the heapsize and other minor adjustment to the GC settings (e.g. young gen size, survivorratio) has gotten us predictable short GC pauses again.

For the DN however we are still suffering from periodic long GC pauses. What I observe is that exceptionally long GC pauses occur every 6 hours (Full GC). Now I assume that Cloudera setting a default of 6 h for the blockreport interval `dfs.blockreport.intervalMsec` is contributing to this pattern.

What I'd like to understand is if there are suggestions how I can approach this problem, where I need to find GC settings that both cater for normal operation memory allocation (seems to be mostly fine) as well as the rapid allocation I'm seeing every 6 hours for a few minutes.

The DN servers have 256G RAM & 20 physical cores

This is Java Hotspot jdk1.7.0_67.

My current, suboptimal settings are:

```
-server 
-Xmn5g 
-Xms12884901888 
-Xmx12884901888 
-XX:SurvivorRatio=3 
-XX:+UseParNewGC 
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC 
-XX:+CMSConcurrentMTEnabled 
-XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=60 
-XX:+CMSParallelRemarkEnabled 
-XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly 
-XX:+ScavengeBeforeFullGC 
-XX:+CMSScavengeBeforeRemark 
-XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=15
```

I'd also be interested to hear if instead of tweaking the JVM there is also a way to influence the blockreport to be less aggressive?

See gc log for the time-range in question:
http://hastebin.com/zafabohowi

Comment: you should enable timestamped GC logging (`-XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:+PrintGCDetails`) and attach a log covering the range in question. CMS full GCs are what you want to avoid since they are single-threaded and thus very slow, so its cause will be of interest.

Comment: @the8472 please see the link to the log. It has one instance of a particularly costly GC of 25.76 sec.

Comment: this looks like a single-threaded (real time == user time) old gen collection, but I thought it should print something like "concurrent mode falure" when that happens. Try throwing further diagnostic flags at it, maybe they'll provide some insight: `-XX:PrintCMSStatistics=1 -XX:PrintFLSStatistics=1 -XX:+PrintHeapAtGC -XX:+PrintPromotionFailure`. Maybe the hadoop block report does a very large allocation that doesn't fit into the young gen or experiences a promotion failure due to fragmentation?

Comment: @8472. I've uploaded the latest log with the additional logging enabled: https://gist.githubusercontent.com/bfloriang/3162a9294bf8277779ce/raw/gistfile1.txt

If I read it correctly there is some memory fragmentation but appart from that I'm not entirely sure what the correct measures are to eliminate the long pauses at regular intervals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, running the log through [GCViewer](https://github.com/chewiebug/GCViewer) it simply seems like there's a burst of activity (e.g. starting 17:09) that fills up the old generation until it causes some failures (at 17:15).

Simply try bumping the heap size to give it more breathing room until the task has finished.

Beyond the *concurrent mode failure* there still seem to be some relatively long pauses, try applying [these options](http://blog.ragozin.info/2012/03/secret-hotspot-option-improving-gc.html) to see if they can shave off some milliseconds.

Comment: yeah, shrinking the young gen also makes more room in the old gen for those long-running tasks, i.e. gives it more breathing room for old objects